# How to check if entity id exists or valid?

Tags: 8, entities

I have created a *content entity type*. When I save form, I got id in routing url, like:

```
entityform/1

entityform/2
```

But if I directly access some *non-existing id* like `entityform/999`, **page dies.**

In **watchdog**, it is showing error,

> Error: Call to a member function get() on null in Drupal...

I can not call function get() on the fields of entity, if entity doesn't exists.

```
$content_type = $entity->get('ctype')->value;
```

How to apply this check, whether entity actually created or not?

Comment: Are you fetching the field value or you are checking if content type is 'dsf'

Comment: `ctype` is the field of an entity. I'm getting this field value from `$content_type = $entity->get('ctype')->value;`. But what If I'm fetching the field value of entity that no where exists. Thatswhy it is giving error, 'calling functiojn get() on null', because field doesnt et created if there is no entity.

Comment: You can check if the entity object `isset()` or is not `NULL`, and use `get()` only if the condition passes.

Comment: Thanks, I used NULL before, it didn't work, don't know what happen now. Its working. thanks.

Comment: Can you update us the whole snippet of code so that we can could help you better

Comment: @Oana Hulpoi, if you put your comment as answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: The correct behavior is to return a page not found response (403). This is usually done in the route definition, by using entity_form. See how the node module accomplished this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the entity object `isset()` or is not `NULL`, and use `get()` only if the condition passes.

Comment: you can upvote this question, as this thing can be easily missed.

Comment: Is there a way to check without loading the entire entity object into memory?

Comment: See this answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/223866/50538