# How Drupal handles nodes 404 requests?

Tags: 8, entities

I'm curious about how Drupal 8 handles nodes 404 requests. I think there might be a route of 404 and then an internal check - if node id doesn't exists, it simply calls 404 route path.

If this scenario is right, how can I achieve the same for custom entity?

I have a content entity type, but want a 404 redirection if someone access wrong entity id directly similar to any node page which doesn't exists.

Comment: There is only one 404 page. If a page is not found, then the configured 404 page (in the site information settings page) is shown. That's it. There is no difference between nodes or not.

Answer (score 4):

Ah, seeing that this is a follow-up to [How to check if entity id exists or valid?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205023/how-to-check-if-entity-id-exists-or-valid), I think I know what the problem is.

If you ensure upcasting through the route, then Drupal throws a not found exception automatically and shows the 404 page.

So, you need to define your route as /entityform/{your_entity_type_id} and in the controller, type hint the argument YourEntityTypeId $your_entity_type_id. Then Drupal automatically loads the object, gives it to you and returns a 404 page if not found.

Comment: what does this line mean 'type hint the argument YourEntityTypeId $your_entity_type_id;' ? Can you explain this more?

Comment: @SugandhKhanna Type hinting isn't a Drupal thing: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration