# What might cause my "User error" in Watchdog?

Tags: 8, entities

I'm trying to figure out the reason behind this "User error" in watchdog

```
User error: "0" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 102 of /core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).
```

This error comes when I access any non-existing entity like

`myentity/762574527` or `myentity/anything`

On googling, I got [this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1500172) , which states its due to `Token` module.

I uninstalled this module and deleted every content related to it, still this error persists.

Can anyone tell the reason behind this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not connected to the Token module.

You should not try to render a non existing entity. Your code should throw an exception instead:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

  throw new NotFoundHttpException();
```

Or configure the route so that when you have a non existing entity as parameter in the route, drupal will throw this exception automatically. See the answer from Berdir to your last question:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/205054/47547